# Speeding up the output of DSolveChangeVariables

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, performance

I am trying to change the variable in a differential equation using the above mentioned function. This is what I did:

```
FullSimplify[DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][
    Derivative[2][y][z] + (\[Epsilon]*d^2 + U*d^2*(Sinh[z]^4/Cosh[z]^6))*y[z] == 
     0, y, z], y, \[Epsilon]3, \[Epsilon]3 == 1/Cosh[z]^2]]
```

And this is the output obtained:

```
d^2*(\[Epsilon] + U*(-1 + \[Epsilon]3)^2*\[Epsilon]3)*y[\[Epsilon]3] == 
  2*\[Epsilon]3*((-2 + 3*\[Epsilon]3)*Derivative[1][y][\[Epsilon]3] + 
   2*(-1 + \[Epsilon]3)*\[Epsilon]3*Derivative[2][y][\[Epsilon]3])
```

The output is fine. However, it takes some time for Mathematica to come up with this result. Is there a way to speed up  the process?
Any input will be most appreciated.
Regards

Comment: On my computer (Win, 13.3), `DSolveChangeVariables` takes 20 seconds, then `FullSimplify` additional 20 s. Is there any particular reason that you want to speed up this? Do you really have to do this process so many times that it affects the overall performance of your code?

Comment: In 14.0 under Windows 10 on my antique comp it takes 0.234375s.

Comment: @user64494, that is a bit ... unbelievable :) On Wolfram Cloud (14.0), `DSolveChangeVariables` still takes ~13 seconds. Are you sure timing the correct thing?

Comment: It takes 19 s on my machine.

Comment: Hi Domen.  I have  a few more  types of substitutions to make on other similar DEs. Also, I don't know whether I am overlooking a bottleneck somewhere in my rudimentary code  that is causing the "delay". Besides, It will be nice to know if there is a  more effective method of  coding this. Cheers